# MaterializeCSS Icon after Input Field

Tags: css, materialize

From MaterializeCSS' [Text Input](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) page there is a section to prefix an input field with an icon.

```
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
      <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix">First Name</label>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to have the icon come after the input field?

I tried a `suffix` css class and it did not exist. Also moving the `<i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>` section after the input/label moves the icon to the next line.

Comment: A quick look at the output of the example it seems that there's a `prefix` for the input and label too, so to create a `suffix` class you'll need to also add something to the label and input in order to shift everything to the right place.  
The `input-field prefix` class has a `margin-left` of 3rem, which is what is creating the space for the icon to sit in, this idea would need to be converted to pad out the right side for a suffix idea. A different route to this would be to use the `col` setup and put the input field in one column and the icon in the next, avoiding the `suffix` concept.

Answer (score 4):

Materialize created this class for `.prefix` :

```
.input-field .prefix {
    position: absolute;
    width: 3rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s;
    transition: color .2s;
    top: .5rem;
}
```

You can overwrite it in your css and add `right: 0` property to align icon to right :

```
.input-field .prefix{
  right: 0;
}
```

A more cleaner solution is adding a `right` class to `<i>` :

```
.input-field .prefix.right{
  right: 0;
}
```

And add it to `<i>` tags that you want to right aligned.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/n8L7ba4o/)

Comment: In your example I added the `right` class and it moved the icon to the right side but  the input field did not shift. Also it is still taking up space on the left side even though the icon is on the right side.

Comment: So you want a full RTL input box. have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/n8L7ba4o/16/

Comment: No no, I am not looking to have the text be RTL. I want the icon on the right (which is already done with the `right: 0` but I want the input field and label to be moved over to the left. In your example, there is still a gap on the lefthand side